# VLOOKUP matching 3 columns with 3 others in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have this formula in D1:

```
=arrayformula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:C,H1:K,{4},0)))
```

I'm trying to match columns A,B,C with columns H,I,J and pull data in column K.  The formula is currently not matching correctly.  Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0XJzZbhaJXAJk8PU8mecGudp-YNsdNkuL_rdqpOX8Y/edit#gid=2142367581).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first argument of `VLOOKUP` needs to be a single column so the only way how to pull this of with 3 columns is like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A&B1:B&C1:C, {H1:H&I1:I&J1:J, K1:K}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thanks - I entered your proposed formula in M1 but it doesn't populate.  any idea? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0XJzZbhaJXAJk8PU8mecGudp-YNsdNkuL_rdqpOX8Y/edit#gid=2142367581

Comment: @moonshot it won't populate if there is no triple match. I updated your sheet and answer